# Inkscape, align objects top has space between objects

Tags: inkscape, svg, icon, alignment

I'm trying to align object in inkscape to make a heart shape but when alligning there is a very small space between the two objects. How can I get rid of that space ?

[image]

As you can see in the picture, where the object half circle meets the square there is a very tiny white line. That's what I want to get rid off.

PS: [Crosspost](https://superuser.com/questions/1477981/inkscape-align-objects-top-has-space-between-objects) but I think here is more suited.

Comment: Can you share the `.svg` file?

Comment: @samcarter sure https://gofile.io/?c=gdCHSe

Comment: Thanks! I think this probably a rendering issue because the width of the white line seems to change with different zoom levels. Anyway, if you want to combine the shapes in a heart shape, I suggest the `path->Union` option to combine the two shapes into a single one.

Comment: @samcarter oh yeah, it disappears when doing that! thanks. (I'll accept answer if you post is as one)

Comment: There are [easier ways](https://imgur.com/WCImlad) to make heart shapes in Inkscape by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this probably a rendering issue because the width of the white line seems to change with different zoom levels.

Anyway, if you want to combine the shapes in a heart shape, I suggest the `path->Union` option to combine the two shapes (left in the image below) into a single one (right):

[image]

Comment: Yep, it's a rendering issue. Inkscape even has an FAQ item for this: https://inkscape.org/learn/faq/#theres-seam-or-artifact-between-adjacent-objects-sharing-same-border-or-between-patterns